# Kinetic.JS sprite sheet frame rate doubles on each eevent

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

Full Example: http://codepen.io/thomasmurphymusic/pen/efzwC

```
blob.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
   blob.start(); 
    blob.setAnimation('drip');
    blob.afterFrame(20, function(){
      blob.setAnimation('idle');        
    });
});
```

My event listeners seem to be stacking here. That is, on my 2nd mouseover, the framerate is twice as fast (my theory is that there are two event listeners, so the frames event twice as fast), the third time 3x the fourth time 4x, and so on.

How do I prevent more than one occurrence of the event listener every time I mouse over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue you described by moving `blob.start();` outside of your `dripAnimation()` (or `mouseover` event) function.

Like this:

```
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function(){
  var blob = new Kinetic.Sprite({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: imageObj,
    animation: 'idle',
    animations: animations,
    index: 0,
    width: 373,
    height: 414,
    frameRate: 15
  });

  layer.add(blob);

  stage.add(layer);

  blob.start(); 

  blob.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
    dripAnimation();
  }, false);   

  function dripAnimation(){
    blob.setAnimation('drip');
    blob.afterFrame(20, function(){
      blob.setAnimation('idle');
    });
  }

};
```